# LaTeX3 string with umlaute

Tags: expl3

I was wondering how to properly use LaTeX3 strings. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_foo
\tl_set:Nn \l_foo {\"a}
\str_new:N \l_bar
\str_set:Nn \l_bar {\"a}
foo = \tl_use:N \l_foo \\
bar = \str_use:N \l_bar
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I expected to get the following output

```
foo=ä
bar=ä
```

but actually I get the following

```
foo=ä
bar=“”a
```

Do I have to treat an umlaut somewhat special in a LaTeX3 string? Beside that what is the recommendation when to use a `str` and when to use a `tl`? Are there any benefits from one or the other? My background is, that I'm developing a package where some variables are left to the user in order to customize the output.

Comment: In strings all tokens have catcode 12 (space 10), so the backslash doesn't start a command and you are simply seeing the output of "\char92 \char34 \char 97" as backslash has the ascii position 92.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In TeX, and thus in `expl3`, a string has a very specific meaning. A string is a collection of tokens where spaces (character code 32) are of category space (category code 10), and all other tokens are of category 'other' (category code 12). This is a special case of the more general concept of a token list, which is a collection of tokens of arbitrary category codes.

We have both a `tl` and a `str` data type in `expl3` as the latter is useful for 'flagging up' programmatic uses where string values are important. However, at a technical level there is no reason these couldn't be called `tl`s. For storing *text* for *typesetting* you always want to preserve meaning, so `str` would be inappropriate: you want `tl`.